# Fast and simple way to read from stdin one byte at a time in C++

Tags: c++, performance, stdin

The following naive code for reading from stdin and counting the number of occurrences of each byte is extremely slow, taking about 1m40 to process 1 GiB of data on my machine.

```cpp
int counts[256] {0};

uint8_t byte;
while (std::cin >> std::noskipws >> byte) {
  ++counts[byte];
}
```

Doing a buffered read is, of course, much faster, processing 1 GiB in less than a second.

```cpp
uint8_t buf[4096];

uint8_t byte;
int n;
while (n = read(0, (void *)buf, 4096), n > 0) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    ++counts[buf[i]];
  }
}
```

However, it has the disadvantage of being more complicated and requiring manual buffer management.

Is there any way of reading a stream byte-by-byte in standard C++ that is as simple, obvious, and idiomatic as the first snippet, but as performant as the second?

Comment: Possibly cin.get()?

Comment: @Chipster tried it and it is just as slow as `operator>>` when reading one character at a time.

Comment: The only way to get the speed is to do the bulk read.  Not sure what *manual buffer management* you are complaining about since you don't have any in the code you show.

Comment: @NathanOliver hmm? I mean defining the 4096-char `buf`, passing it to `read`, and then processing it up to its length.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be an interesting problem. My results are here:

```
without cin sync      : 34.178s
with cin sync         : 14.347s
with getchar          : 03.911s
with getchar_unlocked : 00.700s
```

The source file was generated using:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.txt count=1024 bs=1048576
```

The first one is my reference, no changes: `34.178s`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *f = freopen(argv[1], "rb", stdin);
    int counts[256] {0};

    uint8_t byte;
    while (std::cin >> std::noskipws >> byte) {
      ++counts[byte];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`:`14.347s`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    FILE *f = freopen(argv[1], "rb", stdin);
    int counts[256] {0};

    uint8_t byte;
    while (std::cin >> std::noskipws >> byte) {
      ++counts[byte];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With `getchar`: `3.911s`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *f = freopen(argv[1], "rb", stdin);
    int v[256] {0};
    unsigned int b;
    while ((b = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++v[b];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With `getchar_unlocked`: `0.700s`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *f = freopen(argv[1], "rb", stdin);
    int v[256] {0};
    unsigned int b;
    while ((b = getchar_unlocked()) != EOF) {
        ++v[b];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My machine config:

```
CPU  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
MEM  : 12GB
Build: g++ speed.cc -O3 -o speed
g++ v: g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0
exec : time ./speed file.txt
```

For me, getchar_unlocked is the fastest way to read bytes without maintaining a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

It will speed up cin by a large amount.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't change how long my benchmark takes. Running on macOS.